# Angular img src is unknown when calling function

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to dynamically change the img src by calling a function that returns the image path, but when I use the code below, the image element shows as `<img src(unknown)/>`

**component.ts:**

```
getMedia(row) {
    this.sharedDataService.inventoryRows.forEach(function(elem){
      if(row.vin === elem.vin){
        console.log(elem.media[0].href);    //logs string correctly
        return elem.media[0].href;
      }
    });
  }
```

this code successfully logs the string stored in `elem.media[0].href` to the console, so I'm confident it is returning the correct path as a string.

**HTML:**

```
<img src="{{getMedia(row)}}" />
//DOM element comes back as <img src(unknown)/>
```

I've also tried the following, as suggested by other Stackoverflow answers, but I don't get the desired DOM element using this either

```
<img [src]="getMedia(row)" />
//DOM element comes back as <img src="null"/>
```

I'm certain that this should be possible, but I'm clearly missing some behind-the-scenes knowledge about its inner workings

Comment: Is `this.sharedDataService.inventoryRows` an async operation? Can you provide that code as well?

Comment: What is the `row` that you are passing as an argument from the html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't actually returning any data from the function, as the `return` keyword in `.forEach` only breaks the loop, and also [`.forEach` only ever returns `undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). The issue can be resolved by substituting `.forEach` for something like `.find` as shown below:

```js
function broken(){
  var list = [1,2,3,4,5];
  var value = list.forEach(function(num){
    if(num == 2)
       return num;
  });
  return value;
}

function working(){
  var list = [1,2,3,4,5];
  var value = list.find(function(num){
    if(num == 2)
       return num;
  });
  return value;
}


console.log("broken", broken());
console.log("working", working());
```

Answer (score 0):

you are returning from the foreach loop and not returning a value from the getMedia function, use for loop its faster and clear

```
 getMedia(row) {
       const data = this.sharedDataService.inventoryRows;
       for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++;) {
         if(row.vin === data[i].vin){
            return data[i].media[0].href;
         }
       }
       return '';
 }
```